# This program cannot read the text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The main program is about a two player game. When a player wins, the variable win is set to 1 or 2 respectively (as a string) and this is written to the file score.txt each time the game is played. When the game is done, I want to check what the score is by counting all the 1's and 2's in the file. This is that part of the program:

```
outfile = open("score.txt", "a")
    outfile.write(win)
    player1score = (outfile.read()).count("1")
    player2score = (outfile.read()).count("2")
```

This doesn't work, the file is created, but it's empty and I get the error:

```
player1score = (outfile.read()).count("1")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: Try giving this a read http://www.afterhoursprogramming.com/tutorial/Python/Writing-to-Files/

Comment: try closing the file after it has been appended, then reopen the file for reading

Comment: You should get rid of those extra parenthesis. They don't need to be there and decrease the readability.

Comment: @user3636636 Thanks that worked! I can't figure out why the scores keep showing up as zero for both players though....

Comment: @Ovi Open a new question if you would like help with your output don't edit in a new question here.

Comment: Also when you read through `read()` method, you simply read all content and go to the end of file so second `read()` returns empty string. You should write sth like `content = outfile.read(); content.count("1"); content.count("2")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You opened it as an appending file stream, not an input.

You need to open it again as reading... Or just store that information in memory.

Comment: I closed the file and then reopned it in reading mode, but I can't figure out why the scores keep showing up as zero for both players